# How to add headers in a Soap Web service JAX-WS

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I am new to java web service. I want to add headers to my web service
I tried to add `@WebParam(name = "noun", header = true)` in my input parameters of web method. I tried something like this

```
@WebService(serviceName = "Server")
public class Server {
@WebMethod(operationName = "DeviceAccess")    
    public String DeviceAccess(@WebParam(name = "noun", header = true) String noun, @WebParam(name = "verb", header = true) String verb ) {
        String returnMessage=noun+verb;
        return returnMessage;
    }
}
```

But when I try to test my web service using tool called 'storm' It shows that header parameters i.e 'noun' and 'verb' in above case shows in body element of request
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can add response headers with custom `Interceptor`. In case of CXF you can extend `org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.AbstractSoapInterceptor` for this and then add it to your service with `org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutInterceptors` annotation.

More info [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html).